# Do any know how get range data in between?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I want to get the data in between two variables by getting it I will get estimate data in the table

```
select rate 
from tbl_reporate 
where purity='IF' 
  AND color='G' 
  AND weight_from >= '1.78' 
  AND '1.78' <= weight_to 
  AND shap='ROUND'
```

I am getting multiple data and not correct

```
13500
27500
35500
46500
74500
```

Comment: ```
16500
27500
35500
46500
74500
```

Comment: Hint: `BETWEEN x AND y`

Comment: What is the data type of weight_to?

Comment: Thank you for your help i am already get my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the canonical way to express the range:

```
and 1.78 between weight_from and weight_to
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
and weight_from <= 1.78 and weight_to >= 1.78
```

This checks wether the given number (`1.78`) belongs to range `weight_from/weight_to`.

Note that this uses literal numbers (without single quotes), not strings (comparison rules are not the same for numbers and stngs!). I would expect both columns to be numeric, but if they are strings you need to convert them:

```
and weight_from + 0 <= 1.78 and weight_to + 0 >= 1.78
```

Comment: its comes under the 1.5 to 1.99

ok